# Loop data with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having my code as

```
function updateData(data){
    data.forEach(function(obj){
        users.find({_id:obj.userId}).toArray(
        function(e, res) {
            obj.userData = res;
            console.log(res)
        }); 
    });
    return data;
}
```

The problem is I am unable to find the updated data, I am trying to update my data and adding one more field to it based on userId. The data parameter is an array containing the output from comments table. hope you understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that `users.find({...}).toArray(function(...){...})` is going to be asynchronous, so there is no way that you can be sure that the db call has been completed and that each `data.obj` has been updated before `data` is returned.

Instead of using the javascript `Array.prototype.forEach()` function, you could use the NodeJS `async.each` function from the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach) by Caolan which would iterate through the array, update each object and then return the `data` object only when all functions calls have completed.

For example:

```
var async = require("async");

function updateData(data){
    async.each(data, function(obj, callback) {
        users.find({_id:obj.userId}).toArray(
            function(e, res) {
                obj.userData = res;
                callback(e);
            }
        );  
    }, 
    function(error){
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same result. I am new with Node.js callback pattern. can you please provide some reference where I can I find more stuff to understand this whole pattern??

Comment: There is a section called "What are callbacks?" in [this tutorial](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4). If you are feeling adventurous then there is [this article](http://callbackhell.com/) about "Callback Hell" and how to avoid it. Do your console log messages show up in your terminal? You should also check `e` to see if an error is being returned